# Instance member 'imageWithColor' cannot be used on type 'UIImage' not reading from my extension function

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

hi i am new in swift4 making a tab view , on hover i want a different color when pressed on tab , for achieving this i have wrote following code , but getting this error .

```
Instance member 'imageWithColor' cannot be used on type 'UIImage'; 
did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

**my code :**
i want to use color literal property inside ***problemIsHere*** text i mention below.

```
let numberOfTabs = CGFloat((tabBar.items?.count)!)
let tabBarSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfTabs, height: tabBar.frame.height)
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: ***problemIsHere*** ,   size: tabBarSize)
```

the imageWithColor is not readable from extension function , here is my extension function code :

```
extension UIImage{
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor , size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}
```

Please help , thanks.

Comment: `UIImage.imageWithColor` that's a Class method (or `static` in Swift) syntax, while your declaration: `func imageWithColor(color:...)` is a instance method. ` func imageWithColor(color: UIColor , size: CGSize) -> UIImage ` => `static  func imageWithColor(color: UIColor , size: CGSize) -> UIImage`, or use a `convenience` init instead.

Comment: You need to make your `imageWithColor` function a `static` function. That is the cause of your error. Then you can worry about passing in the desired color.